# Compare several items bij adding these elements into 2 arrayList

Tags: java, arrays

In an exercise, I have an array with several items.

If each item has 6 or more than 6 characters, these items will go into the arrayList named `list1`. The others items into the `list2`.

I have tried this but my 2 arrayList are inaccurate.

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

String[] tab = {"Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra"};

    for(int i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
      if(tab.length > 6){
        list1.add(tab[i]);
      }

      else{
        list2.add(tab[i]);  
      }
    }

System.out.println("More than 6 characters " +  list1);
System.out.println("Less than 6 characters " +  list2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the length or the array `tab.length` (attribut so no parenthesis) you need the length of the current element : `tab[i].length()` (method so parenthesis)

To simplify this, you could use a `for-each loop`

```
String[] tab = {"Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra"};

for(String elt : tab){
    if(elt.length() > 6){
        list1.add(elt);
    }else{
        list2.add(elt);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for you explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The source of your issue here is on the line `if(tab.length() > 6){`.

What you're currently doing here is comparing the length of the String array `tab` to 6. What you want to be doing is comparing **each element** of the String array `tab` to 6.

For example, `if(tab[i].length() > 6)`

Comment: `String.length()` is a method, you need the parenthesis ;)

Comment: Good catch! Editing